# call postgresql pg_dump.exe from visual basic

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to do a backup of my database from my application made in visual basic (visual studio 2012)

I copy the pg_dump.exe with the necessary dll files to the application root.

Test the pg_dump doing a backup from cmd window and goes ok

This is the code i use to try to call the pg_dump exe but apparently does not receive the parameters i'm trying to send.

```
' New ProcessStartInfo created
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim args As String = "-h serverip -p 5432 -U postgres db_name > " & txtPath.Text.ToString

    ' Specify the location of the binary
    p.FileName = "pg_dump.exe"

    ' Use these arguments for the process
    p.Arguments = args

    ' Use a hidden window
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized

    ' Start the process
    Process.Start(p)
```

When the process start i get this msg:

**pd_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is ">")
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information**

if i type this in cmd the backup is done ok
pg_dump.exe -h serverip -p 5432 -U postgres db_name > c:\db_bak.backup

But i cant make it work from visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your command is just plain wrong. You're invoking `pg_dump`, which wants to *read from* a file, so you don't want to use `>`. That'd write to the file and overwrite it in the process. Instead you'd want `<`, the "read file as standard input" operator.

That's not the immediate cause of your error though. `pg_dump` doesn't understand `>`, `<`, etc. These operations instruct the shell (`cmd.exe`) to do [I/O redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). If you're not running `cmd.exe` then they don't work. To get I/O redirection (`>`, etc) you need to run the process via the `cmd` shell, not invoke it directly.

In this case it's probably better to [use the `-f filename` option to `pg_dump` to tell it to write to a file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) instead of standard output. That way you avoid I/O redirection and don't need the shell anymore. It should be as simple as:

```
Dim args As String = "-h serverip -p 5432 -U postgres db_name -f " & txtPath.Text.ToString
```

Alternately, you can use `cmd /C` to invoke `pg_dump` via the command shell. Visual Basic might offer a shortcut way to do that; I don't use it, so I can't comment specifically on the mechanics of process invocation in Visual Basic. Check the [`CreateProcess` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); VB likely uses CreateProcess under the hood.

Personally I recommend that you do

Comment: can you give me a little example? im kinda lost here

Comment: @Hannibal Instead of using I/O redirection (`> filename`), tell `pg_dump` to write directly to the file with `-f filename`. See the documentation for `pg_dump`.

Comment: @Hannibal Added links and further explanation.